# R: png() Keep X & Y Axis Proportional?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, scale

I've made a correlation plot, where both X and Y axes are the same scale/unit.  My plot has a Title and Legend.  I want to export the image with a given size (inches or cm) for easy assembly into a multi-panel figure for a publication.

When using the png() function to export a plot, is there a way to keep X and Y axes proportional?  The Title and Legend are calculated into the final size of the image, which ends up skewing the proportions of the X and Y axes.  In the past, I'v tweaked width and height manually to try to get the image perfect, but it's guesswork.

If not, are there any other solutions within R?  I can think of ways to crop and paste images together in image software, but I'd prefer to find a solution in R.

Thank you!

```
png(filename = "ABC.png", width = 6, height = 6, units = "in", res = 300)
ggplot(Cor_All, aes(x=log2FoldChange, y=logFC.deseq, color = Color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Genes", values = c("Black", "Green", "Red"),
                     labels =  c("All Genes", "40 Selected Genes", "Genes Lacking Peak")) +
  labs(title = "Total RNA-Seq vs. Rpb1 ChEC-Seq", x="LFC Rpb1 ChEC", y="LFC Total mRNA") +
  xlim(-5, 5) +
  ylim(-5, 5)
dev.off()

[![ABC.png][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzJe9.png
```

Comment: Doesn't `coord_equal()` do the job?

Comment: Sure does!  Just needed to add this as a line to my ggplot.  My mistake was looking for options in png() function instead of ggplot.  Thank you!